# Detect when component is un/attached to the DOM

Tags: typescript, dom, virtual-dom, hyperhtml

I'm moving from React to **hyperHTML** because performance matters. I'm using third-party libraries specifically for dock panel management from [PhosphorJS](https://phosphorjs.github.io/). When I create this 'DockPanel' class I need to attach it to the real DOM tree.

In `React` this is can be solved with the function `componentDidMount` (called right after the virtual nodes are attached to the DOM tree).

So my question, Is there a way to detect when a component is "mounted" and "umounted"? I saw that `HyperElement` has the `dis/connectedCallback` function but in the `hyper.Components` doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hyperHTML.Component` has both *onconnected* and *ondisconnected* mechanism, as [described in the documentation](https://viperhtml.js.org/hyperhtml/documentation/#components-3).

```
class Clock extends hyper.Component {
  get defaultState() { return {date: new Date()}; }
  onconnected() {
    console.log('finally live');
  }
  render() {
    return this.html`
      <div onconnected=${this} >
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is ${
          this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()
        }.</h2>
      </div>`;
  }
}
```

I'm not familiar with PhosphorJS (first time I heard of it) but if it's based on regular DOM nodes you should be fine.